# Not getting crash report data in Fabric Crashlytics dashboard after moving app to another account

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm not getting any crash report data on the application dashboard for an app that I had previously setup and configured on a different organization account. I'm able to upload and distribute builds but the crash report data goes to the previous account's dashboard. I thought deleting the app from the previous account dashboard would fix the issue but after deleting the app I'm not getting crash report data in either account now. I don't want to loose the uploaded builds or release history otherwise I would have tried deleting the app from both places and trying to configure it again from the account where I want to distribute builds and receive crash data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching out. It sounds like the old organizations API keys are still cached in your app. Please clean your app and check the info.plist and run script build phase (or if Android, AndroidManifest and/or fabric.properties file)